# Can I use C++20 concepts for partial template specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I was given an assignment on my computer science class to implement a `String<T>` class in C++ which would have `print` method throw an exception, unless `T = char`. So I defined a method for `template<typename T> class String` this way:

```cpp
void print(std::basic_ostream<T> stream) {
    throw StringTypeError("Can't print with these types");
}
```

And defined a specialization like so:

```cpp
template<>
void String<char>::print(std::basic_ostream<char> stream) {
    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < size; i++)
        stream << charAt(i);
}
```

That totally works, however I've recently found out about concepts and decided to allow usage of `print()` for any type which can be `<<`/`>>` into IO streams. I created a small concept:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept IO = requires(T a) {
    std::cout << a;
    std::cin  >> a;
};
```

And tried to alter my specialization this way:

```cpp
template<IO T>
void String<T>::print(std::basic_ostream<T> stream) {
    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < size; i++)
        stream << charAt(i);
}
```

But the compiler rejected with "Type constraint differs in template redeclaration" error.

Am I making a mistake which can be corrected or is it impossible to use concepts in this way? (*if that's so, is there any concept-like alternatives?*)

Comment: You have to **declare** it (in the class).

Comment: I would DEFINITELY have two different concepts, one for insertion and one for extraction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> is there any concept-like alternatives?

There is an appropriate tool for the job, a particularly nice new feature with concepts and its related requires-clauses, one which is not possible with pre-C++20 SFINAE, namely that *non-template* member functions of class templates can be declared with requires-clauses. This means that you can define both of your mutually exclusive `print` member function in the primary template:

```
template<typename T> 
class String {
    void print(std::basic_ostream<T>&) requires (!IO<T>) {
        throw StringTypeError("Can't print with these types");
    }

    void print(std::basic_ostream<T>& stream) requires (IO<T>) {
        for(unsigned long i = 0; i < size; i++)
            stream << charAt(i);
    }
    // ...
};
```